# How to deal with SELECT(MAX()) in mysql inside a foreach using PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I'm using `SELECT(MAX())` inside a `foreach` loop and this is my code:

```
foreach($_POST['image_Basename'] as $key=>$image_Basename){


    $image_Title = $this->input->post('image_Title');

    $image_Category_Id = $this->input->post('image_Category_Id');


    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_Group_Id, image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id)
                      SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(image_Group_Id) FROM mg_gallery), 0), '$image_Title', '$image_Basename', '$image_Category_Id'
    ");
}
```

The problem is that  for each `image_Basename`, query produces a new number.

For example, if I got 3 `image_Basenames`, it will insert 1, 2 and 3 for those three `image_Basenames`. But I want it to insert the same number to all of `image_Basenames`.

For example, if the max number in the image_Group_Id is 1, then add number 2 for each image_Basename. How can I do that?! I've put

```
SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(image_Group_Id) FROM mg_gallery
```

outside of the `foreach` loop, but it didn't work!!!

**The answer is added below by myself**

Comment: Do you mean it sets 1,2,3 for `image_Group_Id`?

Comment: you should select the max before your loop. if you do it inside the max will be incremented by 1 each time. What does "it didn't work" mean? show the code you tried!

Comment: Change `MAX` to `MIN`. It shall work for your code.

Comment: @Anthony, For example, if the max number in the `image_Group_Id` is 1, then add number 2 in `image_Group_Id` for each new `image_Basename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IT WORKS:**

Specially thanks to Niloy Saha, finally, I got the answer, and this is the code I've used:

```
$getMaxValue  = $this->db->query('SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT MAX(image_Group_Id)), 0) AS image_Group_Id FROM mg_gallery');
if($getMaxValue->num_rows() > 0){
    $group_Id    = $getMaxValue->row_array();
    $image_Group_Id  = $group_Id['image_Group_Id'];
}else{
    $image_Group_Id  = 0;
}

foreach($_POST['image_Basename'] as $key=>$image_Basename){
    $image_Title = $this->input->post('image_Title');
    $image_Category_Id = $this->input->post('image_Category_Id');
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id, image_Group_Id)
                      VALUES ('$image_Title', '$image_Basename', '$image_Category_Id', $image_Group_Id)
    ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED 2**
Try this if it works or not,

```
$maxRs  = $this->db->query('SELECT max(image_Group_Id) AS max FROM mg_gallery');
echo $this->db->last_query();die;  #run this query in your phpmyadmin and debug it.
if($maxRs->num_rows() > 0){
    $maxData    = $maxRs->row_array();
        echo "here :".$maxID  = $maxData['max'];die;
    }else{
        $maxID  = 0;
}
//echo "max : ".$maxID;die;   #check if its returning the corrent maxid or not.
foreach($_POST['image_Basename'] as $key=>$image_Basename){
    $image_Title = $this->input->post('image_Title');
    $image_Category_Id = $this->input->post('image_Category_Id');
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_Group_Id, image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id)
                      $maxID, '$image_Title', '$image_Basename', '$image_Category_Id'
    ");
    echo $this->db->last_query();die;  #check the query its generating is correct or not and run directly at phpmyadmin
}
```

Comment: And the error I get using your code:

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array, 'test', '8e690ea3a804558066f3682f41e89637.jpg', '1'' at line 2

INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_Group_Id, image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id) Array, 'test', '8e690ea3a804558066f3682f41e89637.jpg', '1'

Comment: updated the above code to debug once. It should return the correct maxID and not an array. Check once if the maxID is generating correctly or not and let me know.

Comment: it prints: max : Array

Comment: instead of `echo "max : ".$maxID;die;` write `echo "max : ".print_r($maxID);die;` and let me know.

Comment: Shouldnot happen that way is the `image_Group_Id` column you are fetching an `auto incrementing` column or not? I have updated the above anwer. try it out

Comment: No it's not auto_increment! this time it printed here: , it's blank

Comment: this time it shows : SELECT max(image_Group_Id) AS max FROM mg_gallery

Comment: Yes, and did you run it in your phpmyadmin directly? What did it returned?

Comment: what do you mean by that?! I'm running the code using `xampp`. and as I copied the code above in to my php file, after running I get `SELECT max(image_Group_Id) AS max FROM mg_gallery`

Comment: I ran it in phpmyadmin and the result was max NULL

Comment: after some modifications, I got the Answer and I posted it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what kind of data you have and exactly what you want, but I'll help you towards the right direction:

```
$int_basename = (int)max($this->input->post('image_Basename'));
$str_image_title = $this->input->post('image_Title');
$str_image_category_id = $this->input->post('image_Category_Id');

$query   = $this->db->query("SELECT max(image_Group_Id) AS max FROM mg_gallery");
$int_max = (int)$query->row()->max;

$arr_union = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
    if ($i == 1)
        $arr_union = "SELECT " . ($int_max + $i) . " AS id";
    else $arr_union = "SELECT " . ($int_max + $i);

$str_union = implode(' UNION ', $arr_union);

$this->db->query("
INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_Group_Id, image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id)
SELECT h.id, ?, ?, ?
FROM ({$str_union}) AS h
", array($str_image_title, $int_basename, $str_image_category_id));
```

This would only run the query *twice* and spare your database the trouble of loop queries. I also escaped the values through `$this->db->query()` as intended to avoid mysql injections. This doesn't really require `INSERT ... SELECT` as `INSERT ... VALUES` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should *never* be inserting values directly from the `POST` array. But in the interest of just addressing the question at hand, I'll leave the code as is.

You need to query for the `MAX(image_Group_Id)` before starting the loop and not do a `+ 1` inside the loop. Like this:

```
$get_group_id = $this->db->query("SELECT 1 + coalesce((SELECT max(image_Group_Id) AS group_id FROM mg_gallery), 0)");

$get_group_id_array = $get_group_id->fetch_assoc();
$group_id = $get_group_id_array['group_id'];

foreach($_POST['image_Basename'] as $key=>$image_Basename){

    $image_Title = $this->input->post('image_Title');
    $image_Category_Id = $this->input->post('image_Category_Id');

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO mg_gallery (image_Group_Id, image_title, image_Basename, image_Category_Id)
                      $group_id, '$image_Title', '$image_Basename', '$image_Category_Id'
    ");
}
```

Comment: Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Filename: gallery_model.php

Line Number: 45

this is the error I get when I use your code!

Comment: Try it now. I didn't write out the code between sending the query and retrieving the actual value returned.  The problem, I think, with your attempt to retrieve outside the loop is that you didn't remove the `+ 1` from inside the loop, which is the problem.

Comment: this time the error is: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::fetch_assoc()

Comment: after some modifications, I got the Answer and I posted it